# Cache can't be found by key

Tags: java, spring, caching

```
 @Cacheable(value = "dishDTOs", key = "#root.methodName")
    public List<DishResponseDTO> getAllToday() {}
```

It creates cache with getAllToday key, and I can see it logs:

```
 Key: getAllToday | EventType: CREATED
```

But when I want to evict this cache by another method - it can not be found.

```
   @Caching(
            evict = {
                    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "dishDTOs", key = "getAllToday"),
                    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "dishDTOs", key = "#dishId")
            })
```

And this is exception I have

```
Property or field 'getAllToday' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject'
```

And Intellij Idea warnings

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use `"'getAllToday'"`?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to use two different cache names? One for the getAll, one for individual items. Then you can use the "allEntries=true" rather than specifying the "getAllToday" keyname to evict that cache.